# Convergence in probability : intuition behind this equality

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I don't understand the logic behind the equality.
We have $ P(X_n = n^2) = \frac{1}{n}$

Why : for $ \epsilon $>$ 0 $

\begin{align}%\label{eq:union-bound}
   \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P\big(|X_n| \geq \epsilon \big)&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n=n^2)\\
 \end{align}

I'm really not having the required thought process to solve understand this.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that  you sequence of rv can take only 2 vlaues: zero and $n^2$ with probability $\left\{1-\frac{1}{n};\frac{1}{n}\right\}$, respectively...thus the statement easy follows

---

Let's assume that the sequence $\{X_n\}$ is the one I thought: a sequence taking only 2 values: 0 and $n^2$ with the stated probabilities.

Thus $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)=P(X_n>\epsilon)=\frac{1}{n}$ as you can see in the following drawing

[image]

Comment: I'm really not getting the part where the statement easy follows. I think I just need to see it to realize how obvious it is. I have such a hard time understanding how to deal with this $\epsilon$. I know that $ \epsilon $>$ 0 $. But I don't understand how to use it

Comment: @Valentin : added some further explanations

Comment: thank you so much !! It helped me so much !